# nginx prometheus exporter collected metric was collected before with the same name and label values

Tags: nginx, prometheus

I deployed nginx Prometheus snmp exporter via ansible (https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter). It was working properly, but couple of days ago, exporter stopped sending data to Prometheus. 
After I run this command

> curl localhost:9122/metrics

here is my nginx-exporter-config-j2 file

```
{% for node in test-scratch-nodes %}
server {
    listen {{ node.exporter_port }};
    server_name _;
    location / {
        return 404;
}
        location /metrics {
        proxy_pass {{ test_scraper_url }}?target={{ node.host    }}&module={{ test_scraper_module }};
    }
}
{% endfor %}
```

the system shows errors as,

> An error has occurred during metrics gathering:
>
> 4 error(s) occurred:
>
> - collected metric "RouteRestricted" { label: gauge: } was collected before with the same name and label values
> - collected metric "RouteCongestionLevel" { label: gauge: } was collected before with the same name and label values
> - collected metric "RoutePC” { label: gauge: } was collected before with the same name and label values
> - collected metric "RouteState" { label: gauge: } was collected before with the same name and label values